# Improvement of JS Regex to restrict all letters of a word in a specific range

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm solving the Ranges challenge in [RegexGolf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf), but I'm somewhat stuck in trying to shorten the regex.

Here is a screenshot of the conditions -

[image]

My current solution is `\b[a-f]+\b`. This pattern has the required range `[a-f]` in a word boundary. While this works, the regex has 10 characters, and the result list shows submissions with 8, and even 1 character.

Would appreciate any insights on improving this regex.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't think this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please note that shorter doesn't necessarily means better, faster or better readable. But as this is a golfing challenge:

This site seems to handle every input as a separate string. While the word boundaries you are using are fine, using start and end of string anchors (`^` and `$`) will be 1 character shorter each. I don't see how it could be minimized further, so your regex could be

```
^[a-f]+$
```

Note: One of the 1-score solutions comments, that *i dont know regex but i know javascript*, so I'd guess that there was some cheating involved.

Comment: Thank You! I wonder why I never thought of this solution, especially since at the previous exercise, I did `k$`!